# Is Deena Shan related to Bastila Shan?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I was reading some *Star Wars: Rebellion* (which is considered Legends). There's a character by the name of Deena Shan and it doesn't say so, but I was wondering if she's the descendant of Satele Shan? I checked the Wookieepedia entry for the Shan family and I got no confirmation. Do you guys know?

Comment: Are you referring to the [comic series](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rebellion_(comics)), the [video game](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rebellion_(video_game)), the [board game](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rebellion_(Fantasy_Flight_Games)), or something else?

Comment: Most likely The comic series, as [Deena Shan's profile on Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Deena_Shan) lists multiple appearances there.

Comment: Agree w/ @Thunderforge's question. A link to the material for specificity would be helpful

Comment: Bastila Shan is from the Knights of the Old Republic video game, her descendant Staele Shan is from the mmorpg The Old Republic. Deena Shan was introduced in the Star Wars Empire comic (the Empire series was renamed and continued in the Rebellion series). Bastilia and Staele have a direct connection because the games are connected and the comic is under the Legends banner just  like the games. Is there any other information I could provide that could help with the question?